# Election Comments under profiles

Tags: discussion

Is a current moderator deleting comments under peoples nominations on the election page?

Comments that appear from August 17th for the current moderators have stayed where as most new nominations comments have been cleaned up completely.

I hardly find that to be **fair and in poor taste.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a cleanup from someone above us all.
The SO admin ([Grace Note](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note)) that started the magento SE election deleted them.

[Check this chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23509329#23509329)

Comment: That makes me feel much better. Thank you for linking that!